# My ActionScript's ExternalInterface callback function isn't going through. How can I debug it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

Help, please? It appears that my callback function isn't being called...back. I'm using jQuery, and Flash 8. To access the Flash object, I'm using the jquery swfobject plugin, c.f. (http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples). If you think that I'm not accessing the SWF properly in the first place, please recommend code as to how I would do that. Thanks!

JavaScript Code:

```
$("#songplayer").flash("callCueSong(" + songid + ")");
```

Flash Code:

```
import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.addCallback('callCueSong', null, cueSong);


stop();
pause = false;
pp_btn.hitArea = pause_hit_area;
love_btn.hitArea = love_hit_area;
_root.display_txt.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;

function cueSong(songid) {
    trace('Cueing track ' + songid);
    _root.sid = songid;
    _root.sound_mc.songStarter('sent', false);

}

MovieClip.prototype.songStarter = function(next_direction, feedback) {
      // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was *working*. I was simply uploading the wrong SWF, and not publishing to the right location. I discovered it by putting the following debug code, uploading, and noting that although it appeared in the local debug console, it did not appear in Flash Tracer

```
trace("Availability: " + ExternalInterface.available);
```

Also, I changed security on the Flash. In the HTML, I put "AllowScriptAccess" as "always", and in the SWF, I put:

```
System.security.allowDomain('http://www.mydomain.com', 'http://mydomain.com', 'mydomain.com', 'amazonaws.com');
```

Thanks for looking! Hope you have luck in the future.